# Questions about MPI_Scatter executer & its send buffer allocation

Tags: mpi

My first thought was `MPI_Scatter` and send-buffer allocation should be used in `if(proc_id == 0)` clause, because the data should be scattered only once and each process needs only a portion of data in send-buffer, however it didn't work correctly.

It appears that send-buffer allocation and `MPI_Scatter` must be executed by all processes before the application goes right.

So I wander, what's the philosophy for the existence of `MPI_Scatter` since all processes have access to the send-buffer.

Any help will be grateful.

---

**Edit:**
Code I wrote like this:

```
if (proc_id == 0) {
    int * data = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int) * proc_size * recv_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < proc_size * recv_size; i++) data[i] = i;

    ierr = MPI_Scatter(&(data[0]), recv_size, MPI_INT, &recievedata, recv_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

I thought, that's enough for root processes to scatter data, what the other processes need to do is just receiving data. So I put `MPI_Scatter`, along with send buffer definition & allocation, in the `if(proc_id == 0)` statement. No compile/runtime error/warning, but the receive buffer of other processes didn't receive it's corresponding part of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, and would be a lot easier to understand if you showed some code that you were having trouble with.   Here's what I *think* you're asking -- and I'm only guessing this because this is an error I've seen people new to MPI in C make.

If you have some code like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int proc_id, size, ierr;
    int *data;
    int recievedata;

    ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&proc_id);

    if (proc_id == 0) {
        data = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) data[i] = i;
    }

    ierr = MPI_Scatter(&(data[0]), 1, MPI_INT,
             &recievedata, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("Rank %d recieved <%d>\n", proc_id, recievedata);

    if (proc_id == 0) free(data);

    ierr = MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

why doesn't it work, and why do you get a segmentation fault?  Of *course* the other processes don't have access to `data`; that's the whole point.

The answer is that in the non-root processes, the `sendbuf` argument (the first argument to `MPI_Scatter()`) isn't used.  So the non-root processes *don't* need access to `data`.  But you still can't go around dereferencing a pointer that you haven't defined.   So you need to make sure all the C code is valid.   But data can be NULL or completely undefined on all the other processes; you just have to make sure you're not accidentally dereferencing it.  So this works just fine, for instance:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int proc_id, size, ierr;
    int *data;
    int recievedata;

    ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&proc_id);

    if (proc_id == 0) {
        data = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) data[i] = i;
    } else {
        data = NULL;
    }

    ierr = MPI_Scatter(data, 1, MPI_INT,      
             &recievedata, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("Rank %d recieved <%d>\n", proc_id, recievedata);

    if (proc_id == 0) free(data);

    ierr = MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

If you're using "multidimensional arrays" in C, and say scattering a row of a matrix, then you have to jump through an extra hoop or two to make this work, but it's still pretty easy.

**Update:**

Note that in the above code, all routines called `Scatter` - both the sender and the recievers.  (Actually, the sender is also a receiver).

In the message passing paradigm, both the sender and the receiver have to cooperate to send data.   In principle, these tasks could be on different computers, housed perhaps in different buildings -- nothing is shared between them.  So there's no way for Task 1 to just "put" data into some part of Task 2's memory.   (Note that MPI2 has "one sided messages", but even that requires a significant degree of cordination between sender and reciever, as a window has to be put asside to push data into or pull data out of).

The classic example of this is send/recieve pairs; it's not enough that (say) process 0 sends data to process 3, process 3 also has to recieve data.

The `MPI_Scatter` function contains both send and recieve logic.   The root process (specified here as 0) sends out the data, and all the recievers recieve; everyone participating has to call the routine.  Scatter is an example of an [MPI Collective Operation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/gropp/node76.html), where all tasks in the communicator have to call the same routine.  Broadcast, barrier, reduction operations, and gather operations are other examples.

If you have only process 0 call the scatter operation, your program will hang, waiting forever for the other tasks to participate.

Comment: I post my code snippet, as you see I am thinking in PThread logic, in which share memory acts as communication approach. I do not have much knowledge about mpi.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you did help understanding the principle of MPI.