# Scatter a vector into a variable MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, scatter

I'm trying to send from process with rank = 0 to all other process (1,2,3,4) a value from the vector `n_pointsBuffer`. The problem is that just process 0 gets its value but the others don't. Can anyone explain to me if it's possible what I'm trying to do, if so, how? It's the first time I use MPI.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

MPI::Init(argc, argv);

int num_procs = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

srand(getpid());
int n_points;

if (rank == 0) {
    int n_pointsBuffer[] = { 1000000, 1203100, 1231230, 1231000, 1312322 };
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(n_pointsBuffer, 1, MPI::INT, &n_points, 1,
            MPI::INT, 0);
}

cout << "Rank = " << rank << ", n_points = " << n_points << "\n";

double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n_points; i++) {
    double x = rand() / ((double) (RAND_MAX));
    double f = 1.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    sum += f;
}

double avg_sum = 0;
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Reduce(&sum, &avg_sum, 1, MPI::DOUBLE, MPI::SUM, 0);

if (rank == 0) {
    double pi = 4.0 * (avg_sum / num_procs / ((double) (n_points)));
    cout << "Pi is approx " << pi << " with error " << pi - M_PI << ".\n";
}

MPI::Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because everyone has to call `Scatter()`. Not just the root. Quoting from another [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879496/questions-about-mpi-scatter-executer-its-send-buffer-allocation) :

> The MPI_Scatter function contains both send and recieve logic. The
>   root process (specified here as 0) sends out the data, and all the
>   recievers recieve; everyone participating has to call the routine.
>   Scatter is an example of an MPI Collective Operation, where all tasks
>   in the communicator have to call the same routine. Broadcast, barrier,
>   reduction operations, and gather operations are other examples.

Please note that the same holds for **every** collective operation. An example of using Broadcast is [here](https://github.com/madaan/BVP-MPI-PROJECT/blob/master/SumNELe/sumN.c) (You can also find some other programs in the same repo, these were written by me to test my MPI cluster made of dumped machines) .